# How to check in C, if an argument is a single character or a string of characters?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

let Suppose that I want to create a variadic function which has number of arguments as its first argument, and the other arguments are meant to be strings.

when I call my function with arguments of type strings, everything is fine since the function expects this type of data, but when I call it with a single character for example, BANG! bad move. suppose the program will sometimes receive unwanted arguments like this,
How can I prevent this segmentation fault to happen.
I wrote these code as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
/* my variadic function to print strings arguments */
void args_printer(unsigned int args_number, ...)
{
    unsigned int index;
    char *arg_string;
    va_list arg_ptr;
    
    va_start(arg_ptr, args_number);
    for (index = 0; index < args_number; index++)
    {       
        arg_string = (char *)va_arg(arg_ptr, char *);
        if (arg_string != NULL)
            printf("%s ", arg_string);
        else    
            printf("Wrong data!\n");
    }        
    va_end(arg_ptr);
    
}

int main(void) {
    char *message = "Message : ";
    /*args_printer is working fine with correct data and NULL argument */
  args_printer(5, message, NULL, "La vie", " appartient", " au courageux!");
  
  /* arg_printer is having a segmentation fault once I enter this 'm' or a number */
  args_printer(4, 'm', "La vie", " appartient", " au courageux!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with just `"m"`? Why does it need to be a `char` instead of a single character string?

Comment: This is a known problem with variadic functions: there's no way for the compiler, or the code, to type-check the arguments. The code calling the function needs to get it right. Period.

Comment: @user3386109 Well known variadic functions to the compiler like `printf()` sometimes  offer  type checking, but overwhelmingly compilers do not offer checks for user variadic functions arguments.

Comment: BTW, the cast `(char *)` is not needed in `arg_string = (char *)va_arg(arg_ptr, char *);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I prevent this segmentation fault to happen.

Error checking: [no-such-luck](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_such_luck) with a `f(...)` function.

---

Usually just code the *m* as a little *string* instead as `char`:

```
// args_printer(4, 'm', ...
args_printer(4, "m", ...
```

---

Alternative to form a *string* on the fly:

```
char ch = 'm';
...
// args_printer(4, ch, ...
args_printer(4, (char[2]){ch}, ...
```

Comment: `(char[2]){ch}` that is... still a string though. Why even bother with that?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli If the string was fixed, sure `"m"` would be preferred.  Yet if a string was needed dynamically to form from a `char`, this provides a one line alterative.

Comment: Yeah, it's unclear whether OP needs this or just doesn't know that one-character strings are a thing.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Fair enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'm actually learning, I just wanted to make sure if there is a way, even a tricky one  or not. But  now it is very clear in my mind

Comment: @sombamanyaMukendiDieudonne There _are_ tricky ways, like wrapping each _and every_ argument in a macro that uses `_Generic` to type check.  Yet at some point, in C, code is like riding a bicycle, _without_ training wheels. You go fast, but may fall down.